# arrow keys are not functional in sqlplus

Tags: keyboard, sqlplus, key

I find that the arrow keys don't work on the sqlplus console.
For example if I press left arrow key, it shows like

```
SQL>^[[B
```

Does any solutions exist to solve this problem?

Comment: I would also like a solution to this. There are plenty of valid scenarios i.e. editing your own command after noticing a typo. Even if there were other navigation or command history keys (a la vi) that would be helpful too.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use a third party utility called [**`rlwrap`**](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/#rlwrap).

> rlwrap is a readline wrapper, a small utility that uses the GNU
>   readline library to allow the editing of keyboard input for any other
>   command. It maintains a separate input history for each command, and
>   can TAB-expand words using all previously seen words and/or a
>   user-specified file.

So you will be able to use arrows and also get a command history as a bonus.

After you have installed the utility run `sqlplus` the following way:

```
$ rlwrap sqlplus
```

Comment: Unfortunately won't work for any lock-ed down systems i.e. customer sites :(

Comment: You can download a binary version : http://tylermuth.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/static-version-of-rlwrap-for-sqlplus/ if you can't install it.

Comment: On debian systems one may install rlwrap using this command: sudo apt-get install rlwrap -y

Comment: Wow. So impressed by this. OracleDB is so enterprisy. Very exciting technology. ORA-00933. Have to buy this product, amazing.

Comment: rlwrap rpm packages could download from http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/45322991/dir/redhat_el_5/com/rlwrap-0.42-1.el5.x86_64.rpm.html

Answer (score 14):

As [Johnny suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10282648/4794), you can install the [rlwrap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10282648/4794) utility to manage command history for any other command, including `sqlplus`. Another useful trick is to alias the wrapped version of `sqlplus` so you don't have to type `rlwrap sqlplus` every time.

```
alias sqlplus="rlwrap sqlplus"
```

Comment: thanks!  On EL7, to make the alias permanent across logins for your oracle user, as the oracle user run: echo 'alias sqlplus="rlwrap sqlplus"' >> ~/.bashrc