# Fixing arrow keys in IEX in TMUX session

Tags: bash, elixir, tmux, xterm, elixir-iex

I use TMUX and vim for everything, and recently started working with Elixir. Whenever I run an elixir process, including `iex -S mix`, I cannot use the error keys as it instead prints out `^[[A` for the up arrow, `^[[B` for the down arrow, etc.

How can I fix TMUX or iex so they can properly communicate the arrow keys?

EDIT 1:

Output of `echo $TERM` is `tmux-256color`. My terminals are set up following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@dubistkomisch/how-to-actually-get-italics-and-true-colour-to-work-in-iterm-tmux-vim-9ebe55ebc2be

I have three machines set up with the same terminals and same config files (shared by a GitHub repo). On two machines (one iMac, one MacBook Prop) the up arrow works and on one machine (MacBook Air) the up arrows don't. How can I go about finding what is not working on the one machine?

EDIT 2:

Elixir and erlang versions are the same:

```
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.5.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.9.1 (compiled with Erlang/OTP 22)
```

Comment: What is the output of `echo $TERM` inside of TMUX?

Comment: @JonasDellinger edited the original question with more info

Comment: mh sadly this doesn't seem like the culprit :/

Comment: Which login shells are used on your machines? 
Are the settings in iTerm -> Preferences -> Profiles Tab -> General section different?

Comment: The limitation is probably in iex. The usual workaround would be [`rlwrap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890636/arrow-keys-are-not-functional-in-sqlplus/10282648#10282648).

Comment: @ThomasDickey you are my hero! That worked great, if you want to answer the question I'd be happy to mark it as solved

Comment: I had a similar problem to that, tried everything: erl flags, different installs of erlang ane elixir, rlwrap (its just not as good) etc. But the problem fixed itself on the latest upgrades I did on my arch linux install, i will probably never know the culprit

Answer (score 0):

Elixir's interactive shell [*iex*](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/introduction.html) does not know about arrow-keys (for command-history) by default.  According to its [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html), you can enable that when starting it:

- start with a parameter:

  `iex --erl "-kernel shell_history enabled"`
- start with an environment variable:

  `export ERL_AFLAGS="-kernel shell_history enabled"`

As an alternative, [`rlwrap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890636/arrow-keys-are-not-functional-in-sqlplus/10282648#10282648) can be used for this (and other programs).